# Location of chakras

Tags: chakras

I have to apply some oil at Anahata, Vishuddhi and Ajna chakra. But I don't know it's location. Searching on google also I didn't got any quality diagram or an answer. Where are they located?

Comment: You can see this image (https://post.healthline.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/7-chakras-header-1-732x549.png). Ajna is between the two eyebrows, Vishuddhi is the throat chakra and Anahata is at the middle of the heart. You can now understand where to apply if you consult the image.

Comment: The chakras exist in the subtle body - not the gross physical body.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda atleast for this question you commented to the point.

Comment: @Rickross so there existence doesn't corresponds to points but they exist in a large area of our body as shown in the diagram.

Comment: If you are advised to apply on the Ajna Chakra then you have apply on the spot between the eyebrows. Where usually tilaks are worn and bindis worn by ladies on your forehead. Similarly for Anahat you have to apply at the middle of your chest (refer to the image given). For Vishuddhi apply at the base of the throat. @Shivakk

Comment: Refer to another image here (https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-4iPn9DdtNPE/Ww6ZvH6Jb6I/AAAAAAAAU9o/bGzBJArI7EIdcXs2Tx5nj0JzSqM2ivcvgCLcBGAs/s1600/twelve-spots-to-wear-tilak.jpg). So you have to apply oil on the spots marked in the image as 1, 4 and 3. If you still have doubts then please respond here. @Shivakk